# I am seeing duplicate folder names in my url in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter framework.  I have sub folders with name "services" in my controller and view folders. I have duplicate folder names in my url when I enter a particular section of my site and can't get the page:

```
http://localhost/mysite/services/services/view1
```

The second "services" in that url shouldn't be there.

It should look like this:

```
http://localhost/mysite/services/view1
```

my route is this:

```
$route['services/view1'] = "services/view1/one";
$route['services/view2'] = "services/view2/one";
```

my controller is this:

```
$this->load->view('services/view1', $data);
```

and

```
$this->load->view('services/view2', $data);
```

so, when I click on the first link it works right as it must, but then when I click on the second link I see the problem that I described above.

can someone give any solution? thank.

Comment: your route problem  $route['services/view1'] = "view1/one";  used this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last, I solve the problem.

I have change my route like this:

$route['view1'] = "services/view1/one";

and just remove "services" from this link 
services/viev1">viev1

thank you guys for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Here your route problem

```
$route['services/view1'] = "services/view1/one"; 
$route['services/view2'] = "services/view2/one";
```

means your url like this

```
http://localhost/your_codeigniter_directory/service/view1/one
```

you need below url

```
 http://localhost/your_codeigniter_directory/view1/one
```

> your-codeigniter_directory is service so your url

```
http://localhost/service/view1/one
```

your change route like this

```
 $route['services/view1'] = "view1/one";
```

Answer (score 0):

your problem is regex delimiter in router. All urls that finished in service/view1 take the controller. So, I consider that your base_url (in application/config/config.php) is "http://localhost/mysite/", then:

```
$route['^services/view1$'] = "services/view1/one"; // "^" to init and "$" to end in regular expression
$route['^services/view2$'] = "services/view2/one";
```

Comment: Great! It was useful to you my example?